# Using default modifier in UI classes

Tags: java, user-interface

As I am always told: to make a field private in any cases to achieve Encapsulation.

However components in a UI are always static and final. So I chose to make some of these component public (can be accessed anywhere) and some others with default modifier (can be accessed within the package).

But as I am new to java, I am not sure if it is good. I want to know its advantage and the risks it might have.

```
class Frame extends JFrame{
    ...
    public static JLabel label_resource;
    public static JLabel label_shipNum;
    public static JLabel label_status;
    public static JTextArea[] textAreas_fleet;
    public static JTabbedPane tabbedPane_fleet; 
    public static JToggleButton toggleButton_bathingPause;
    JTextField textField_url;
    JTextField textField_params;
    JPanel panel_login;
    JPanel panel_status;
    JPanel panel_action;
    JPanel panel_control;
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is very little to encapsulate in the UI, that usually applies to the domain. Please share the code that's troubling you as a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: `However components in a UI are always static and final` in which context is this `always happen`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the code is too long too show you (1000+ lines). I will post some.

Comment: @nachokk in the situation you don't change components and layout of the ui. Like notepad, it just need a toolBar and a textArea, and I will make these two final and static.